# Strange behavior of autocomplete for ColorData

Tags: front-end, mac-os-x, autocomplete

I'm seeing very weird behavior when autocompleting:

[image]

Not sure if this is a bug. Is it?

[image]

(I have OSX v10.2)

Comment: Sorry for being dense, but what is the weird or unexpected part?  When I type `Color`, I get 'ColorData' as the first suggestion just like you do.  Then when I click on "Choose Color Scheme" I get the drop down menu to choose a scheme.

Comment: @JasonB Note the transparent background of the drop down menu for choosing a scheme. On Win7 x64 with version 10.2 I have non-transparent white background. I think it is a little bug in the color scheme chooser palette of the autocomplete menu on OSX.

Comment: Surely you can't be running on OS X 10.2. Perhaps you mean OS X 10.10.2, which is an only slightly out-of-date version of Yosemite.

Comment: I'm am (also?) running on OS X 10.10.2. I can duplicate your result. The transparency doesn't affect the functioning of the pop-up dialog, so this is only a cosmetic bug, but I encourage you to report it.

Comment: I'm seeing that with *Mathematica* 10.2 under OS X 10.10.5.

Comment: This should be reported to WRI. There's not much we can do here except to confirm it.